# how to use pyspark writing to JDBC without column name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

My question is really really simple.

I'm use pyspark to export a hive table to SQL Server.

I found I exported column names as lines in the SQL Server.

I just want to do it without column names.

[image]

I don't want these columns in tables...

My pyspark code here:

```
df.write.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://10.8.12.10;instanceName=sql1", "table_name", "overwrite", {"user": "user_name", "password": "111111", "database": "Finance"})
```

Is there an option to skip column names?

Comment: Please show a small sample of the DataFrame you’re attempting to write. From the looks of it, the _rows_ (why do you say columns?) contain copies of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the JDBC connector isn't actually what adds those header lines. 
The header is already present in your Dataframe, it's a known problem when reading data from Hive table.

If you're using SQL to load data from Hive, you can try filtering the header with condition `col != 'col'`:

```
# adapt the condition by verifiying what is in  df.show()    
df = spark.sql("select * from my_table where sold_to_party!='Sold-To Party'")
```